# New to coding, debugging problem, Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

so i can't get my debugger to work, I keep getting the error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined" I have gathered I need to import a test framework, but I don't honestly know here that would be, or how to import it. I am still learning and i am fairly new to coding. here is a picture of my vscode launcher.json, from my shallow understanding the problem is in here but i am lacking in the knowledge of how to fix it. im more than happy to give more or diffrent information to help solve the issue.  [image]

```js
var _; // globals
console.log('test');

describe('About Applying What We Have Learnt', function() {
  var products;

  beforeEach(function () {
    products = [
      { name: 'Sonoma', ingredients: ['artichoke', 'sundried tomatoes', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
      { name: 'Pizza Primavera', ingredients: ['roma', 'sundried tomatoes', 'goats cheese', 'rosemary'], containsNuts: false },
      { name: 'South Of The Border', ingredients: ['black beans', 'jalapenos', 'mushrooms'], containsNuts: false },
      { name: 'Blue Moon', ingredients: ['blue cheese', 'garlic', 'walnuts'], containsNuts: true },
      { name: 'Taste Of Athens', ingredients: ['spinach', 'kalamata olives', 'sesame seeds'], containsNuts: true }
    ];
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/

  it('given I\'m allergic to nuts and hate mushrooms, it should find a pizza I can eat (imperative)', function () {
    var i, j, hasMushrooms;
    var productsICanEat = [];

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
      if (products[i].containsNuts === false) {
        hasMushrooms = false;
        for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j += 1) {
          if (products[i].ingredients[j] === 'mushrooms') {
            hasMushrooms = true;
          }
        }
        if (!hasMushrooms) {
          productsICanEat.push(products[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    expect(productsICanEat.length).toBe(1);
  });

  it('given I\'m allergic to nuts and hate mushrooms, it should find a pizza I can eat (functional)', function () {
    var productsICanEat = [];


    /* solve using filter() & all() / any() */

    var pizzas = _(products.name).filter(function(product) {
      return !product.containsNuts && !_.contains(product.ingredients, "mushrooms");
    });

    console.log(pizzas);


    expect(productsICanEat.length).toBe(0);
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/

  it('should add all the natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5 (imperative)', function () {
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i += 1) {
      if (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }

    expect(sum).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  it('should add all the natural numbers below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5 (functional)', function () {
    var sum = FILL_ME_IN; /* try chaining range() and reduce() */

    expect(233168).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/
  it('should count the ingredient occurrence (imperative)', function () {
    var ingredientCount = { '{ingredient name}': 0 };

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
      for (j = 0; j < products[i].ingredients.length; j += 1) {
        ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] = (ingredientCount[products[i].ingredients[j]] || 0) + 1;
      }
    }

    expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  it('should count the ingredient occurrence (functional)', function () {
    var ingredientCount = { '{ingredient name}': 0 };

    /* chain() together map(), flatten() and reduce() */

    expect(ingredientCount['mushrooms']).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });

  /*********************************************************************************/
  /* UNCOMMENT FOR EXTRA CREDIT */
  /*
  it('should find the largest prime factor of a composite number', function () {

  });

  it('should find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3 digit numbers', function () {

  });

  it('should find the smallest number divisible by each of the numbers 1 to 20', function () {


  });

  it('should find the difference between the sum of the squares and the square of the sums', function () {

  });

  it('should find the 10001st prime', function () {

  });
  */
});
```

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in your launcher.json file? Look on the bottom right. It gives you the file and the line number that this error occurs on.

Comment: It says node is running and the error is in **koans/AboutApplyingWhatWeHaveLearnt.js** on line 4.  The error is that it is using a variable called `describe` that hasn't been defined.  Perhaps if you share the text of that file?

Comment: why do you ask the same question a few hours later?